# How to show Android GregorianCalendar in ListView?

Tags: android, listview, date

I want to show the String in ListView 
Exmaple: 2013/10/10 18:50
and i use GregorianCalendar

```
GregorianCalendar cld = new GregorianCalendar (2013,1,1,1,1);
cld.get(cld.DATE);
String str = cld.toString();
String[] list = {str};
```

but in listview show java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=138470580000,areFieldsSet=true.....]

not 2013/10/10 18:50 , how to do that? thx

Answer (score 1):

That is appearing because you are using the .toString() directly which returns you a raw representation of the GregorianCalendar Object.

In order to show a text representation you need to use a SimpleDateFormat. Something like this:

```
GregorianCalendar cld = new GregorianCalendar (2013,1,1,1,1);
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm");
String[] list = {formatter.format(cld.getTime())};
```